# How do I add the file used to import data with django-import export?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am using `django-import-export` to allow my app's users to import their own data to the database. I have created the appropriate resource with the fields that are needed. It works as it should.

What I am trying to do next is add the used file alongside the users imported data, so I can show the users their imported files and their info.

I am not saving the files to my server, just processing them.

Firstly, I have created a new model called `FileImported` to hold the info for the file used for the import:

```
class FileImported(models.Model):
     filename = models.CharField()
     name = models.CharField()
     size = models.DecimalField()
     extension = models.CharField()
     date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.filename
```

Then I had to pass the file info:

```
result = imported_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True,
                                           raise_errors=False,
                                           file_name=import_file_name,
                                           user=self.request.user,
                                           file_size=import_file_size,
                                     file_extension=import_file_extension)
```

After that, I create a new `FileImported` model object before importing:

```
class ImportedResource(resources.ModelResource):

   .........

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        file_name = kwargs.get('file_name', 'unknown')
        name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
        file_size = kwargs.get('file_size', 'unknown')
        file_extension = kwargs.get('file_extension', 'unknown')
        user = kwargs.get('user', 'unknown')

        file_name_model_object = FileImported .objects.get_or_create(filename=file_name,
                                                                name=name,
                                                                size=file_size,
                                                                extension=file_extension,
                                                                user=user)
```

I have added the following fields to my model:

```
imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
imported_file = models.ForeignKey(FileImported, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank = True,null=True)
```

The most obvious way is to add the `imported_file` field to the fields in the resource. That way, the user will have to fill that themselves or leave it blank or hidden, I suppose, and then I would fill it later.

I am not sure how to add the newly created `FileImported` model object to each row of my data, if it's not one of the fields.

I am thinking of using `before_save_instance` and do something like:

```
def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
    instance.imported = True
    instance.imported_file = ?
```

The issue is passing the imported_file info(?).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to overwrite 2 methods:-**

```
class EmailResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('email',)
    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, **kwargs):
        self.file_name = kwargs.get('file_name', 'unknown')


    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
         if not dry_run:
             instance.filename  = self.file_name
```

As you can see in sample

> after_import_instance method will get filename after import of file. and added filename in object
>
> before_save_instance method will have instance , just need to assign 
>   filename to instance

This is not perfect solution but work well for me.